# How to install software in openSUSE 11.2

Tags: linux, installation, plugins, opensuse-11.2

I've just started using Linux — openSUSE 11.2 — after 15 years of using Windows. From Windows, I'm used to installing any software with just a few clicks. I'm confused by Linux's `.tar`, `.rpm`, &c. files; I don't even know how to download them.

How can I install browser plugins and other software, like VLC, in openSUSE 11.2/Linux?

Answer (score 2):

Read through the documentation the the SuSE website here http://en.opensuse.org/Package_management and here http://en.opensuse.org/YaST_Software_Management . If you can't get a grasp on it switch to Ubuntu and read through the documentation on there wiki https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ it is one of the easiest and most widely supported distros out there right now.

I recommend switching to Ubuntu because it seems like you are trying to convert over from Windows... Ubuntu is great for that its like linux with training wheels :)

Note: Not saying SuSE isn't a good starter distro just saying Ubuntu is great mainly because of the huge community surrounding it.